# React Native keyboard events not working with android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to adjust only one component of my view when keyboard is shown so i set 
**"adjustNothing"** in my android manifest file and I handle the movement of the component with **"keyboardDidHide"** event listener and with **TextInput onFocus**. I tried this but I'm not getting anything from the listener when keyboard hides...

Here is my AnidroidManifest File:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

And this is what i want to do when keyboard hides:

```
keyboardDidHide() {
this.animateS(false);
}
```

so it animates back in place.

I tried with **adjustResize** and **adjustPan** but they move the whole view up and i don't want that.
the animation is a simple translate up when keyboard is shown and down when did hide event triggers.

In the docs:

> Note that if you set android:windowSoftInputMode to adjustResize or 
>       adjustNothing, only keyboardDidShow and keyboardDidHide events will be 
>       available on Android
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard

Is this a bug with react native or am i doing something wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Change the config param "adjustNothing" to "adjustPan" can solve my problem. Only "adjustPan", do not set with "adjustResize".

Answer (score 0):

This is an error in the React Native Documentation.

As [andreicoman11](https://github.com/andreicoman11) stated in [this reply](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2852#issuecomment-141712317) to a github issue: `... keyboard events are actually not triggered with adjustNothing because of the way it's implemented, and unfortunately there's no way around that  ...`

React native failed to document that at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard