# React Native: keyboardDidShow listener not firing when android:windowSoftInputMode is set to "adjustNothing"

Tags: android, react-native

I have
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`
set in AndroidManifest.xml

Added listener to Keyboard:

```
componentDidMount() 
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow);
  }
```

Defined the function:

```
_keyboardDidShow = () => {  
    console.log('_keyboardDidShow called');
}
```

But `_keyboardDidShow` is never called when `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`.
It works fine when `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` or `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

From the docs:

> Note that if you set android:windowSoftInputMode to adjustResize or adjustNothing, only keyboardDidShow and keyboardDidHide events will be available on Android. keyboardWillShow as well as keyboardWillHide are generally not available on Android since there is no native corresponding event.

[Keyboard Reference](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard)

I have looked at:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2852 (looks like an open bug)
[React Native keyboard events not working with android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52849428/react-native-keyboard-events-not-working-with-androidwindowsoftinputmode-adjus?rq=1) (solution: set windowSoftInputMode to adjustPan)

I can not have `android:windowSoftInputMode` set anything other than `adjustNothing`

Anybody have a solution or workaround to this issue?
.
.
.
**Update January 2020:** Documentation has been updated to

> Note that if you set android:windowSoftInputMode to adjustResize, only keyboardDidShow and keyboardDidHide events will be available on Android. If you set android:windowSoftInputMode to adjustNothing, no events will be available on Android. keyboardWillShow as well as keyboardWillHide are generally not available on Android since there is no native corresponding event.

Comment: any updates on this?